# Jenkins multibranch pipeline with gitea

Tags: maven, jenkins, gitea

I want to design a Jenkins Pipeline for a multibranch design.

Developers will develop in a branch called "feature". Every time a commit is done maven should execute Tests and do a build.

Once the feature is ready the developer will create a Pull Requeest on the Gitea Server to branch development. This PR triggers another build, test, etc. Once this is successfull the PR is allowed to be accepted by the team manager.

Development Branch can be merged to master branch by another PR. This PR will trigger again build and test. But also creation of Docker image and pushing to the central registry and deploying.

Can anybody help me with the Jenkins file?

That is my current file:

```
pipeline {
agent any

triggers {
    pollSCM('*/15 * * * *')
}

options {
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
}

tools {
    maven 'Maven 3.8.3'
    jdk 'jdk11'
}

stages {
    stage('Initialize') {
        steps {
            sh '''
                echo "PATH: ${PATH}"
                echo "M2_HOME: ${M2_HOME}"
            '''
        }
    }

    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            sh 'mvn clean package'
        }
        post {
            success {
                junit 'target/surefire-reports/**/*.xml'
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Don't.  Upgrade to a modern CICD solution.  Gitlab is nice.

Comment: First use gitea plugin int Jenkins if you like to go that path..furthermore don't disable concurrent builds and use `withMaven(...)` parts of pipelines...